# Raspberry PI 4 won't boot into desktop

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, terminal

Hey guys I'm stuck in a tricky situation  :D

Today I tried to rotate my touchscreen via adding a line in the libinput.config file.
Something must have gone wrong because now when I boot just the terminal shows up and I can't get trough to the desktop.

- Changing the boot options in [i]raspi_config[/i] to "B4  Desktop or
  B3 Desktop" doesn't work
- startx[/i] didn't work, it gives me an "...fatal server error...no
  screens found..".
- startlxde-pi[/i] gives me a "....WARNING ...... cannot open display"
- I tried opening the [i]40-libinpt.config[/i] file but it seems to be
  empty which I really don't understand.
- I tried manually typing the code into the empty
  [i]40-libinput.config[/i] file based on a version of this file I
  found on GitHub, but this also doesn't work. (Maybe it's because the
  file I found online was outdated, or I made a typing mistake or this
  file has nothing to do with my problem)
- Connecting to my Pi via SSH worked once but only gave me a
  blue-screen.
- I know the easiest way would be to write a new image to the sd-card
  but that isn't an option for me since 2 hours I sealed the housing of
  my PI so I can't really open it anymore to acces the sc-card. (please
  don´t ask why I sealed it (long story)

So if anyone is familiar with a problem like this, please help me out!  ;)

Comment: Can you boot from usb and try fixing by rewriting the SD card from an image on the USB?